# Why conceptually cut a beam or else? (method of sections)

Tags: statics, structural-beam

This question is related to structural design, and statics:

When studying a beam, for example using the sections method, why do we make a conceptual cut?

Answer (score 0):

A conceptual cut simply allows us to analyze that specific beam instead of using the method of joints, which requires analysis of all the beams. Or in other words, its a lot faster and efficient to solve.

[This shows how tedious it can be.](https://youtu.be/GXlMR_nK7rg)